# vb.net simple regex query

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to learn how to use regex to remove all gibberish characters from a string except for alphanumeric and : . and the newline character, whatever it may be.

I am using this

```
TextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "[^:.0-9a-zA-Z ]+?", "")
```

But my result seems to remove all the newline characters too, I thought this is what the ? at the end of the regex query did, tell it to exclude the newline character from the replacement?

Thanks for your input guys

Comment: are you using singleline mode..

Comment: No, the text box is multiline ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
[^:.0-9a-zA-Z\r\n]+
```

`?` is not required

Comment: I tried this but it didn't remove any of the gibberish characters

Comment: Two comments: You don't need to escape the dot inside a character class. And I would use `\r\n` instead of `\s\n` - `\n` is already a part of `\s`, and `\s` matches spaces and tabs, too, which may not be desired.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much guys. This is tricky to grasp at first think i'm going to buy a book on it.